# Routing Error Due to a group prefix in my route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

In my routing if i remove the {page} prefix it works completely fine but when i put it i get an error. For other it is working fine but it is not working for this route: Route::get('/{categories}', 'AdminVisible\CostIncludeController@index');
My AdminPageController:

```
    public function index($page)
    {
        $page = Page::where('Pages_Slug_Name',$page)->firstorFail();
        $pages = Page::all();
        return view('admin.pages.page',[
            'page' => $page,
        ],compact('pages'));
    }
```

My CostIncludeController:

```
    public function index($categories){
        $pages = Page::all();
        $packages = Package::where('slug',$categories)->first();
        return view('admin.pages.costinclude',[
            'packages' => $packages,
        ],compact('pages'));    
    }
```

My Route:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false,'login' => false]);
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/')->name('login')->uses('Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/')->name('login')->uses('Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'AdminVisible\HomeController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::prefix('pages')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/','AdminVisible\AdminPageController@pages')->name('pages');
        Route::prefix('{page}')->group(function() {
            Route::get('/','AdminVisible\AdminPageController@index')->name('page');
            Route::get('/banner', 'AdminVisible\BannerController@index');
            Route::get('/why-with-us', 'AdminVisible\WhyWithUsController@index');
            Route::get('/testimonials', 'AdminVisible\TestimonialsController@index');
            Route::get('/about', 'AdminVisible\AboutController@index');
            Route::get('/about-why-with-us', 'AdminVisible\AboutWhyWithUsController@index');
            Route::get('/general-information', 'AdminVisible\PackageController@index');
            Route::get('/package-program', 'AdminVisible\PackageController@index');
            Route::get('/cost-exclude', 'AdminVisible\PackageController@index');
            Route::prefix('cost-include')->group(function() {
                Route::get('/', 'AdminVisible\PackageController@index');
                Route::get('/{categories}', 'AdminVisible\CostIncludeController@index');
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

My blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('style')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/Admin/sql-data-viewer.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">   
    <style></style>
@endsection
@section('content')
    <section class="data-viewer">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h3>Select Package to change</h3>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn add-data text-white rounded-pill">Add &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></a>
      </div>
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr class="data-head">  
                <td scope="col" style="width: 5%"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 8.7%">Id</th>
                <td scope="col">Includes</td> 
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach ($packages->costIncludes as $include)
              <tr class="data">
                <td scope="col" style="width: 6.5%"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;"><a href="">{{$include->id}}</a></th>
                <td scope="col" class="text-justify" style="width:696px">{{Str::limit($include->Cost_Include,100)}}</td> 
              </tr>                                
                @endforeach
          </tbody>
      </table>

    </section>
@endsection
```

With {page} prefix:

[image]

Without {page} prefix:

[image]

With {page} prefix when i do dd():
[image]

Without {page} prefix when i do dd():
[image]

Comment: try to `dd($packages)` before jumping to conclusion

Comment: @N69S look up i have added what it shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CostIncludeController@index, add the new variable. The router is expecting you to handle two variables.

```
public function index($page, $categories){
    $pages = Page::all();
    $packages = Package::where('slug',$categories)->first();
    return view('admin.pages.costinclude',[
        'packages' => $packages,
    ],compact('pages'));    
}
```

You can confirm the cause of the error by doing a `dd($categories)` inside your controller function in both cases.

Comment: i did even though the route is current it shows null which means i think page not found. but if i remove the page prefix from the route and do it it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we need to pass `$page` parameter in the `CostIncludesController`. This same question is answered in this post:

[I am having trouble with my route in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411787/i-am-having-trouble-with-my-route-in-laravel/63412338?noredirect=1#comment112129412_63412338)

Comment: It looks to me like they did include the essential parts of the answer here and then linked for reference.    This answer may be on the short side, but it looks complete to me.